# do_docker.sh from Android NDK tutorial errors out

Tags: docker, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following the Android NDK tutorial at [here](http://wiki.ros.org/android_ndk/Tutorials/BuildingNativeROSPackages), when running the do_docker.sh command, the build errors out, it does pull down the docker images, and build a few packages, but when it gets to urdfdom, it starts erroring out, not finding members of classes and namespaces. The first error it gives is:

```
In file included from /opt/roscpp_output/target/include/urdf_model/twist.h:44:0,
                 from /opt/roscpp_output/libs/urdfdom/urdf_parser/src/twist.cpp:38:
/opt/roscpp_output/target/include/urdf_model/pose.h: In member function 'void urdf::Vector3::init(const string&)':
/opt/roscpp_output/target/include/urdf_model/pose.h:78:25: error: 'stod' is not a member of 'std'
```

I'm sure this is a missing include somewhere, but since this is part of the docker image I really didn't know where to look, tried retrying a few times in case this was a linking issue, and no change. This is running it on a Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit machine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240526/do_docker.sh-from-android-ndk-tutorial-errors-out/) by [cjr2401](https://answers.ros.org/users/23180/cjr2401/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Issue was solved by Gary Servin of ekumen_labs, after pull request https://github.com/ekumenlabs/roscpp_android/pull/49 was merged the build no longer errors out.

---

Originally posted by [cjr2401](https://answers.ros.org/users/23180/cjr2401/) with karma: 16 on 2016-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0